# mod_rewrite 404 error trying to rewrite URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have website that is using unfriendly URLs and I want to change them using mod_rewrite.

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.website.nl/?p=2
```

and I want it to be

```
http://www.website.nl/about-us
```

When I use this on my local server it works correct but on the live webserver it doesnt

I use this code in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about-us$ /?p=2 [L]
```

I already checked if mod_rewrite is enabled and in my apache2handler it is enabled so it should work shouldn't it?

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing the leading `/` (forward slash) in your pattern, try:

```
RewriteRule ^/about-us$ /?p=2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I still get the 404 error "The requested URL /about-us was not found on this server."

Comment: And you restarted Apache after the change? Is there anything useful in Apache logs? /var/log/apache* or /var/log/httpd* on most systems

Comment: I cant restart apache.. not able to access that part of the server... Same thing for the logs:( So maybe that is causing the problem?

Comment: I forgot you're using .htaccess so no restart is required, but it would certainly be helpful to read the logs to see if they hold anything interesting. Do you actually know if the machine is setup to allow .htaccess files in the first place? Have they ever worked?

Comment: The machine could have "[AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride) None" or something similar preventing these directives from working within a .htaccess file

Comment: I think you have a good point there... Something tells me that there were problems with .htaccess on the server... Maybe they dont allow .htaccess files at all... I think that I have to make a call to my hosting partner. Thanks for the information and keep you updated:)

Comment: You got an up vote;) Only got one question... Is there a way to realise what I want with PHP only?

Comment: FWIW, in a per-directory .htaccess file the slash (`/`) prefix on your pattern should be omitted (as you have in your original code). The value of `RewriteBase` (which should be `/` in the root .htaccess file, although you can be explicit and include this) is removed from the beginning of the URL before it is matched against the pattern. Only in a VirtualHost context should the slash prefix be included. You can't do an internal rewrite in PHP (only redirects).